# ViewPager scroll layout behavior not working with Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

I'm dealing with something strange related to `ViewPager`, `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`.

In my layout, I've got a standard Material Design setup, such as:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="...">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/grey_900"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabBackground="@color/grey_900"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white_1000"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        ...
        app:layout_behavior="com.inkstinctapp.inkstinct.FabBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My ViewPager contains 4 fragments with this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:tint="@color/white_1000"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't get the Toolbar to scroll, I've tried every combination of:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

None of them seems to work except if I remove the `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` from my viewpager, which is not ok because the viewpager goes under the AppBarLayout.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in `RecyclerView` in your fragment layout

Comment: Which version of appcompat do you use ? 23.2 had some bugs with AppBarLayout + SwipeRefreshLayout + SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: @Rehan nothing, the toolbar is still not scrollable.. thank you by the way

Comment: @marco I'm on 23.4.0, still having problems maybe

Comment: more info are here. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201775

With the 23.1.1 all works well. but i don't know if this is the real problem

Comment: @marco unfortunately (or fortunately) this is not my case.. the swiperefreshlayout works well and is scrolling good, the problem is the link with the toolbar

Answer (score 2):

Here is a broad layout implementation of the behaviour you want to achieve.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
 <AppbarLayout/>
 <Viewpager 
 .
 .
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
 <FloatingActionButton/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

add behaviour to the underlying `ViewPager` and it does work. Now let's say your `AppbarLayout` is a custom implementation with a `ToolBar` a `TabLayout` and a custom view say a `LinearLayout` this is how that code should implement the `scroll` attribute.

```
<AppBarLayout>
    <CollapsingToolbarLayout
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
        />

    <Toolbar
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="+id/title_container"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        />

    <TabLayout /> <!-- no flags -->
</AppBarLayout>
```

Further you can experiment with the flags and their values. But remember, `AppbarLayout` is a vertical `LinearLayout` with superpowers. So, place your views accordingly.
[Try this blogpost for details](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)

Comment: This seems legit, unfortunately I can't test right now since the app design has changed since then, I will try later for sure. Also thanks for the link to the blog, that will be very useful

Comment: @Matteo I have continuously been experimenting on these components since they were first released. Do not worry, It will surely work. Now the QuickReturn behaviour mostly depends on the Complexity of the Layouts in the Viewpager as well. Welcome though!

Answer (score 0):

Try wraping your toolbar inside CollapsingToolbarLayout like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@color/ezy_green"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/gray_background"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And dont forget to add scrollview behavior to your Recycler View and to set rest of the attributes to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

you should use **Coordinate layout** as parent layout  to have access to (app:layout_behavior ) in your view pager .

Answer (score -1):

You can try it;

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

For Example code;

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainScreen">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <!--
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    -->

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!--<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container">-->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<!--</FrameLayout>-->
```